# Invalid Cast Expression?

Tags: vb.net

How do I get rid of invalid cast expression from the Values in the Combobox to fit in the equation in `examgrade`?

I tried to resolve it by looking it up on MSDN, and the like but couldnt figure it out.
I tried using `Examgrade = ().ToString` but that did not work.

Hope you guys can point me in the right direction. FYI this is my first real program, I successfully made this once in C# but deleted the source files, so this is Visual Basic and a hell of a lot easier to get this far.

**The asterisks mark the problem line**

```
Public Class Calculator
Dim quarter3 As Integer
Dim quarter4 As Integer
Dim desiredgrade As String
Dim examgrade As String

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    quarter3 = TextBox1.Text
    quarter4 = TextBox2.Text
    desiredgrade = ComboBox1.Text
    ****examgrade = ((desiredgrade - (quarter3 * 0.4) - _
    (quarter4 * 0.4)) / 0.2)****

    If examgrade > 100 Then
        Label5.Text = examgrade + " YOLO"
    ElseIf examgrade < 0 Then
        Label5.Text = "Impossible"
    Else
        Label5.Text = examgrade
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender _
As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _
ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim A As Integer
    Dim B As Integer
    Dim C As Integer
    Dim D As Integer
    A = 90
    B = 80
    C = 70
    D = 60
    ComboBox1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you put **Option Strict On** as the first line of that file, it will show you where the types of variables don't match with what you're assigning to them. Also, why the ComboBox1.EndUpdate() without the corresponding ComboBox1.BeginUpdate(), especially as you aren't changing ComboBox1?

Answer (score 2):

`desiredgrade` is a string

```
examgrade = ((Double.Parse(desiredgrade) - (quarter3 * 0.4) - _
            (quarter4 * 0.4)) / 0.2).ToString()
```

I am using `Double`. You can also use `Integer` if required.

```
examgrade = ((Integer.Parse(desiredgrade) - (quarter3 * 0.4) - _
            (quarter4 * 0.4)) / 0.2).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a specific reason for having examgrade as a String, try the following:

```
Dim examgrade as Integer

examgrade = ((CInt(desiredgrade) - (quarter3 * 0.4) - _
(quarter4 * 0.4)) / 0.2)
```

VB will automatically convert examgrade to a String when you assign it to your label.

Comment: ...or do it one of the ways Siddharth recommends....I'm almost positive he knows more about VB than I do :)

Comment: There are several ways of doing it. I guess the user is storing the value of the combo in a variable and hence the user declared `desiredgrade` as a string  :) He could have alternatively also done `Dim desiredgrade as Interger = Integer.Parse(ComboBox1.Text)` and like you mentioned also declared `examgrade ` appropriately. A `Double` in this case I guess...

Comment: @TylerG You wrote "VB will automatically convert examgrade to a String when you assign it to your label," however, it is better to explicitly use examgrade.ToString to avoid late binding and also to allow it to compile with option strict on.